# What's wrong with my query? Cannot fetch records

Tags: php, mysql

My query isn't working. It does not print the record, but in phpmyadmin it does bring up a record.

```
 $sql1 = "SELECT fullname FROM addresses WHERE userid = 1 LIMIT 1";
 $result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {

    $fullname = $row['fullname'];

 $i++; }
 echo $fullname;
```

UPDATE:

It was that my table did not have a unique key.

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? Do you get an error message? Have you checked [`mysqli_error()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)? Does the query just return zero rows?

Comment: it comes up empty

Comment: So `$i` is 0 when you `echo $fullname;`? (I'm not actually sure if you initialize that value anywhere…)

Comment: "Anyway, it was that my table did not have a unique key." I would be **_very_** surprised if that was the case. Nothing in your query requires a unique key on your table… I'm quite sure the problem is what my answer below tells you (`mysqli_fetch_row` is indexed numerically).

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You didn't need while loop for set single records from database. Below i have updated your code for single record.

```
 $query = "SELECT fullname FROM addresses WHERE userid = 1 LIMIT 1";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo "Full Name:". $row['fullname'];
```

Comment: Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Please add some context so the OP understands what you fixed.

Comment: Its just sad to see OP prefers answer that can be `copy-pasted` to get the result easily instead of reading manuals and guides to help him very much and understand the problem much better.

Comment: The difference between `mysqli_fetch_assoc` and `mysqli_fetch_row` isn't that one fetches single records…

Answer (score 4):

From [the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php):

> Fetches one row of data from the result set and returns it as an enumerated array, where each column is stored in an array offset starting from 0 (zero).

Your value is in `$row[0]`, not `$row['fullname']`.

If you want an associative array, use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) or [`mysqli_fetch_array`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php).

Comment: And if you @obreezy insist on using `$row['fullname']` then use `fetch_array`. I am also wondering why is there a need for a `while loop` if you only need a single record because of your `LIMIT 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe mysql_fetch_assoc should be the way to go for this type of data retrieval, however, to give you an answer following your code, here it is.

```
$conn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
mysqli_select_db($conn, $database);
$i = 0;

$sql1 = "SELECT fullname FROM addresses WHERE userid=1 LIMIT 1";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result1)) {

    $fullname = $row[0];

$i++; }

echo $fullname;
```

You're getting the data using the index name

> 'fullname'

Like so,

> $fullname = $row['fullname'];

But if you display the value of $row before the while loop, you can see that the option available is the actual numbered index only.

Also, you need to make sure that you're using **mysqli_connect** and **mysqli_select_db** when using **mysqli_query** and **mysqli_fetch_row**.